# Android use FFMPEG to encode h.264 from camera

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-camera, h.264, android-ffmpeg

I got an Android board (Nanopi M3, Android 5.1). I want to use FFMPEG to encode what I have captured from the camera to h.264 format. What input source should be put in the command in FFMPEG? I don't know how to set input source as camera in command.

Comment: According to the publicly available data, Nanopi M3 uses the Samsung Octa-Core Cortex-A53 S5P6818 SoC, which supports 1080p 60 frame video decoding and 1080p 30 frame encoding in hardware.

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to use the NDK compiler FFmpeg source.you can get so library.

Then you use to collect the Camera data through jni calls for H264 encoding FFmpeg.

Comment: *Eric*, please restore the link to your blog post. I believe the whole series contains very useful information, which is not easily available elsewhere. For me, Google Translate did a wonderful job, but it did not handle the comments in code. It would be helpful if you expand your answer here a little more.

Comment: BTW, how is 劍術 related to ffmpeg? I understand that both require many hours of exercise, but is there something more than that?

Comment: @AlexCohn  you can read this project [Android Camera FFmege Topic](https://github.com/EricLi22/FFmpegSample/releases)，and there hava some articles can help you.The hope can help you